# Cross-Domain Posting in ASP.Net loses Form Fields

Tags: asp.net, cross-domain

I have 2 ASP.Net applications in a solution.  One is pretty much a testing harness for a 3rd party app that POSTs data into the primary application.  I tried to mimic this functionality by doing a basic HTML form and setting the action to point to the main application; however, the Request.Form NameValueCollection was empty.  I tried doing it in ASP.Net using a 307 redirect and I had the same issue.  I temporarily have moved the temp form into the main project so I can continue testing.

Here is the 307 Redirect code that I was using:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.StatusCode = 307;
Response.StatusDescription = "Temporary Redirect";
//redirect to a different app.
Response.RedirectLocation = "http://localhost:xxxx/default.aspx";
Response.Flush();
```

Is there a way to do cross domain POSTing in ASP.net web forms?  It works in the same domain but not different domains for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a non-server-side <form> i.e. with **no runat="server"** attribute, and just set the ***action*** attribute to the URL you want to post to:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:xxxx/default.aspx">
    ...
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this initially and the Request.Forms collection still came back empty.

Comment: Might be worth tracking the request at the HTTP level to see exactly what is being sent in the POST data - tools such as Firebug's Net panel or a proxy server such as the one that comes with Burp Suite (http://www.portswigger.net/suite/) should help with this.